# trouble with sound on my steam

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, steam

every time I am in Game on steam the sound keep lowering and then every sound disappears
and the sound will only come back when i close the game from steam itself

i have been having this problem in 4 days and i want to know what this problem is

what i discover is when i go to sound and fixes the sounds then it just comes back for a while
and then the sound disappears..i can only see the game but i cant hear voices or sounds

even the backrounds sounds disappears out side of steam

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with other programs with sound then it could be the problem with Steam itself. Try reinstalling Steam.

Comment: I have reinstalled steam twice..but this is just so annoying v_v